# gcc giving different result for windows and linux

Tags: c, int

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int x=2;
    x=x++;
    printf("%d",x);
    return 0;
}
```

Output according to my logic :
2

Output on windows :
3

Output on Linux:
2

Why is windows giving 3 as output.
From what I understand x++ increments 2 to 3 but return back 2. So x should have 2.Is windows evaluating this anything different.

Similarly:

```
#include<stdio.h>
 int main()
 {
    int x=2,y=4;
    x=x++ + ++y;
    printf("%d %d",x,y);
    return 0;
 }
```

Output according to me :
7 5

Output in windows :
8 5

Output on Linux :
7 5

Again the same situation.

Please help.....

Comment: For a lengthier description, read [Undefined behavior and sequence points](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176328/undefined-behavior-and-sequence-points).

Comment: So much not searching for dups, so much garbage:(

Comment: 'Member since today' what a surprise:(   Tell you prof/TA not to issue such homework his deadbeat students.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`x = x++` is undefined behavior so the two compilers are generating two different pieces of code.

Just `x++` should suffice for your first piece of code.

[Here is a question with your exact problem for the second piece of code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949433/why-are-these-constructs-using-undefined-behavior)